# MySQL order group of records by alphabetical order

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE `hh_members` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` text,
  `hh_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `relation` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Data:

```
insert  into `hh_members`(`id`,`name`,`hh_id`,`relation`) values (1,'Ramzee',1,1),(2,'Trats',1,2),(3,'Alpino',1,2),(4,'Frazier',1,4),(5,'Abraham',2,1),(6,'Woo Wu',2,3),(7,'John',2,3),(8,'Marie',3,3),(9,'Cruze',3,2),(10,'Jinga',3,1),(11,'Abraham',4,1),(12,'Kyla',4,2),(13,'Juanita',4,3);
```

Query so far:

```
SELECT * FROM hh_members
ORDER BY NAME, hh_id, relation
```

What output should be:

Records grouped by 'hh_id' and 'relation' i.e relation=1 should be the top most. While these two being true, they should also sort 'name' of relation=1 in alphabetical order.

In other words, when we grouped data by hh_id and relation, it should sort each group/data section (ordered by hh_id), alphabetically.

Example Output:

Should be ordered by 1, 2, 3 or alphabetically A, J, R, keeping the same group structure.

[image]

Comment: your output should relate with inserted data...so that reader can understand easily

Comment: Its an example output, key is sorting by name column when the records are already sorted by hh_id, relation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select left(h.name,h.hh_id) as name1,h.* from hh_members h inner join (
select name,hh_id as hid from hh_members where relation=1) r on r.hid=h.hh_id
order by r.name,h.hh_id,h.relation
;
```

Comment: Also have to order 'name' alphabetically where relation is 1

Comment: Your query sorts with hh_id and relation, which is fine up to this point, but I also want this very same result sorted alphabetically where relation is 1, hope this makes it clear

Comment: If two names are exactly the same with 'relation'=1 then this query not maintains the grouping of people with same hh_id

Comment: Use this data set to check/confirm:
insert  into `hh_members`(`id`,`name`,`hh_id`,`relation`) values (1,'Ramzee',1,1),(2,'Trats',1,2),(3,'Alpino',1,2),(4,'Frazier',1,4),(5,'Abraham',2,1),(6,'Woo Wu',2,3),(7,'John',2,3),(8,'Marie',3,3),(9,'Cruze',3,2),(10,'Jinga',3,1),(11,'Abraham',4,1),(12,'Kyla',4,2),(13,'Juanita',4,3);